# Finding how many consecutive numbers there are

Tags: java

I need to find how many consecutive numbers come up in my random number generator, I have the program working except for the consecutive numbers part. Here is what ive got. I have tried many things but for some reason I just cant figure it out, please help! There is 1000 numbers and 500 random numbers come out, then I found the smallest and the largest values and then the average. Now I need to find how many consecutive numbers come out f.e. 9, 10, 11 or 55, 56, 57... 
I am also getting this error...
--Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
    int num, largest, smallest, sum = 0, count = 0;
    int programnumber = 6;
    header (prw, programnumber);
    double average = 0;

    Random gen = new Random();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("randomdata.txt");
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 500; i1++){
        num = gen.nextInt(1000);
        fw.write(num + "\n");
        count++;

    }
    fw.close();

    File numfile = new File("randomdata.txt");
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(numfile);
    largest = infile.nextInt();
    smallest = infile.nextInt();
    largest = 0;
    smallest = 999;
    while (infile.hasNext()){
        num = infile.nextInt();
        System.out.println(num);
        if (num > largest){
            largest = num;
        }
        if (num < smallest){
            smallest = num;
        }
        sum = sum + num;
        count++;
        }
    average = (double) sum / count;
    System.out.println("The largest is: " + largest);
    prw.println("The largest is: " + largest);
    System.out.println("The smallest is: " + smallest);
    prw.println("The smallest is: " + smallest);
    System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
    prw.println("The average is: " + average);

            // here is the part where I am stuck
    int prev, consec=0;
    prev= infile.nextInt();
    num= infile.nextInt();
    while (num >= 0) { 
        if (num >= prev){  
            consec++; 
            prev = num; 
            num = infile.nextInt();
        }

    }
    System.out.println(consec);








    prw.close();
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you gave us example inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Seems to me you ran your input file to the end before you started looking for "consecutive" numbers (whatever that means).

Comment: And that bottom  loop will loop forever the first time that `num >= prev` is false, since nothing will change after that.

Comment: (And you need to clearly define "consecutive".  I doubt that you know what it is you mean by that term.)

Comment: Consecutive is defined, it numbers in ascending order like, 1, 2, 3...

Comment: So is 1, 2, 3 one "consecutive number", two, or three?

Answer (score 0):

Can't `num` be less than zero?
The error is in your if:

`(num>=prev)`

doesn't mean they are consecutive. Only the first is greater or equal.
It should be `(num+1==prev)`.

Also, you're reading all the file to find what's the largest, smallest and the average, there's nothing to read when verifying consecutive numbers.

**EDIT**:

This part of code:

```
largest = infile.nextInt();
smallest = infile.nextInt();
largest = 0;
smallest = 999;
```

is discarding the first two numbers.

Comment: Why don't you calculate how many consecutive numbers there is when you are calculating other things? Or you can open the file again.

Comment: So put the if statement into the while?

Comment: The solution is up to you. We pointed the errors here. But no one will code for you. Just watch out for not reading new int values and discarding them.

Comment: If the answer fits, you should accept it and tag the comments that added something useful for the question.